# Extracting the Package name from fully defined class names using R scripting

Tags: r, regex, regular-language

I have following sort of data set(ds1) in my CSV file that includes class Name and corresponding faults. I intend to extract or filter Package Name from the data having number of faults equal to 2 using R script.

```
Class                              Faults

org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer   2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer   2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete    1
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Deltree   2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.DependSet 2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.DependSet 2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.DependSet 2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ear   2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ear   2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Echo  1
org.apache.tools.ant.Exec   2
org.apache.tools.ant.Exec   2
```

I have written following code, but, it does not produce desired output

```
dschanged<- subset(ds1, grep( "/^([^\\.]+)/", class) & Faults==2 )
```

Technically, I require proper regular expression to pull the string before last dot(.) to generate following output.

```
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs       2
org.apache.tools.ant                2
org.apache.tools.ant                2
```

Comment: Would `grepl` be more appropriate?

Comment: Can you resolve it using `grepl`?

Comment: The `"/^([^\\.]+)/"` has one serious issue: you are using regex delimiters `/` that should not be used in R regex functions. Besides, when you escape a `.` in the character class, you make it a PCRE only compatible expression (no longer TRE compatible). However, to get the string before last dot, you'd need `"^(.*)\\."` (then you have a captured value inside Group 1) or a PCRE one `"^.*(?=\\.)"` (with `perl=TRUE`).

Comment: @Mr.Awan you should accept answers that works for your question

Comment: @sayandasgupta I haven't got the solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` (and `grepl`) are inappropriate for this: you aren't filtering based on textual content. You are (a) filtering based on `Faults`, and (b) changing the text in `Class`.

Your data:

```
ds1 <- structure(list(Class = c("org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Deltree", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.DependSet", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.DependSet", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.DependSet", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ear", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ear", "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Echo", "org.apache.tools.ant.Exec", "org.apache.tools.ant.Exec"),
                      Faults = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L)),
                 .Names = c("Class", "Faults"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Filter on `Faults` (you already had this). You only need one of these two commands, they both do the same thing; the major differences are in readability (personal preference) and performance (the second one, in this case, takes about 35% less time, though since they are both measured in microseconds, it seems silly to compete).

```
ds2 <- subset(ds1, Faults == 2)
ds2 <- ds1[ds1$Faults == 2,]
```

Update `Class` to remove the last word (and dot):

```
ds2$Class <- gsub("\\.[^.]*$", "", ds2$Class)
ds2
#                            Class Faults
# 1  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 2  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 4  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 5  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 6  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 7  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 8  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 9  org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs      2
# 11          org.apache.tools.ant      2
# 12          org.apache.tools.ant      2
```

Note: this can also be done with `sub` instead of `gsub`, but the latter is my first-reach since most of my uses deal with larger and repeating regexes. The major (only?) difference between the two is that:

> `'sub' and 'gsub' perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively`

(from `?sub`).

I know of no tool that does *both* the filtering and changing in a single command (though perhaps `data.table` does, I don't know).

Similar to @egnha's solution (that uses `magrittr`), here's one using `dplyr`, which many people allege is very easy to read and adapt (at the potential cost of performance):

```
library(dplyr)
ds2 <- ds1 %>%
  filter(Faults == 2) %>%
  mutate(Class = gsub("\\.[^.]*$", "", Class))
```

Since I mentioned performance, here's a comparison:

```
microbenchmark(indexing = { ds2 <- ds1[ds1$Faults == 2,]; ds2$Class <- gsub("\\.[^.]*$", "", ds2$Class) },
               subset   = { ds2 <- subset(ds1, Faults == 2) ; ds2$Class <- gsub("\\.[^.]*$", "", ds2$Class) },
               dplyr    = { ds1 %>% filter(Faults == 2) %>% mutate(Class = gsub("\\.[^.]*$", "", Class)) })
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  indexing   71.841   87.7045  109.4496  104.2975  120.7075  269.493   100
#    subset  102.473  115.6020  147.0108  139.1230  165.5620  287.726   100
#     dplyr 1067.030 1156.3745 1323.1174 1225.4805 1351.2920 4270.308   100
```

For the record, `dplyr` used in this way is not often this speed-poor in comparison to other methods. It is not commonly *faster*, but it is not often an order-of-magnitude slower.

Comment: @r2evans — Nice benchmarking. I wouldn't have expected dplyr to be so much slower in this case. Any insight as to why?

Comment: No, though in my experience the difference lessens with larger data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without any fancy regex’s: split each `Class` string on the dots, then dot-paste all but the last substring.

```
library(magrittr)  # Provides pipe operator `%>%`

dschanged <- subset(ds1, Faults == 2)
dschanged$Class <- dschanged$Class %>%
                     strsplit(split = "[.]") %>%
                     sapply(function(x) head(x, -1L) %>% paste(collapse = "."))
```

Note that strings without dots will be transformed to empty strings. It is also quite a bit slower than the solution suggested by @r2evans.

Comment: You really should include non-base libraries with your solution. Not everybody is fluent enough to know this is using `magrittr`.

Comment: @r2evans — I'd overlooked that, thanks. Change made.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are looking for filtering based on class name.
Just do it in 2 steps.

```
# Filter
dschanged <- ds1[ds1$Faults == 2,]
# Extract package name
dschanged$class <- sub('(.*)[.](.*)','\\1',dschanged$class)
```